# isvalid() function in symfony always give false

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have created a form and i am using validation on it but whenever i click on submit it not redirect and shows the same page.Even i have set the default values then also no help.
please help me.
Even i have check on varuious form no help.

```
registration form class

    class registrationform extends sfForm {
        //put your code here
        protected static  $option=array('Lab Technician','Lecturur','Assistant Professor','Professor','H.O.D');
        public function configure() {

           $this->setWidgets(array(
               'first_Name'=>new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('default'=>'hello'),array('class' => 'textView'),array('default'=>'hello')),
               'middle_Name'=>new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('default'=>'hello'),array('class' => 'textView')),
               'last_Name'=>new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('default'=>'hello'),array('class'=>'textView')),

               'age'=>new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('default'=>'hello'),array('class'=>'textView')),




           ));


        $this->setValidators(array(
          'first_Name'    => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => 'The message field is required.')),
          'middle_Name'    => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => 'The message field is required.')),
          'last_Name'    => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => 'The message field is required.')),

           'age'    => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => 'The message field is required.')),

            ));
        $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('contact[%s]');
        }


    ****action.class.php****
```

this is a class i which i am having my action class code.

```
    public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
      {
       // $this->forward('default', 'module');
       $this->registration_form = new registrationform();

        if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
        {
            $this->registration_form->disableLocalCSRFProtection();
          $this->registration_form->bind($request->getParameter('contact'));


          if (!($this->registration_form->isValid()))
          {
               echo"\hiol";
            $this->redirect('registration/thankyou?'.http_build_query($this->registration_form->getValues()));
          }
        }


indexsuccess


<?php echo stylesheet_tag('form');?>

<div class="page">
<div class="form"  >
    <form action="<?php echo url_for('registration/index') ?>" method="POST">
    <div class="row" id="head">
        REGISTRATION FORM
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="columnLabel"><?php echo $registration_form['first_Name']->renderLabel()?></div>
    <div class="columnView"><?php echo $registration_form['first_Name']->render()?></div>

    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div ><?php echo $registration_form['first_Name']->renderError()?></div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="columnLabel" ><?php echo $registration_form['middle_Name']->renderLabel()?></div>
    <div class="columnView" ><?php echo $registration_form['middle_Name']->render()?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="columnLabel"><?php echo $registration_form['last_Name']->renderLabel()?></div>
    <div class="columnView"><?php echo $registration_form['last_Name']->render()?></div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
    <div class="columnLabel"><?php echo $registration_form['age']->renderLabel()?></div>
    <div class="columnView"><?php echo $registration_form['age']->render()?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="columnLabel"><input class="button" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
        </div>
<!--        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Your action class is not saving the form if it's valid. You should save and redirect if the form is valid:

```
if ($this->registration_form->isValid())
{
   $this->registration_form->save();
   $this->redirect('registration/thankyou');
}
```

If you need the form value on the next page, don't pass them in url, but flash instead:

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash('registration_form', $this->registration_form->getValues());
```